# Array data not being updated on second routing to component

Tags: angular

I am building a full-stack chat-game application in angular with a nodejs/socketio backend, and I am having an issue with my "waiting room" component, which is where clients go when they are waiting for everyone to join a game and then for the host to start it. If I load the component it works fine, but then if I go away and load it again later, for any reason, the component does not display the array data despite correctly receiving it and even updating the model correctly. I have no idea why this data is not displaying, and even stranger something appears to be deleting the data model when I try to interact with it.

I figured out that the data is being delivered correctly and the model that my template binds to should be updating correctly. There appear to be no issues of this kind with any other templates.

script for the template:

```js
init(){
    this.hosting = this.client.hostingGame;
    if(this.hosting){
      this.startReadyEnabled = false;
    } else {
      this.ready = false;
      this.startReadyEnabled = true;
    }
    this.client.resetHandlers([this.manager]);
    this.client.socket.emit('query-players', (value)=>{
      let players: Array<Player> = new Array<Player>();
      for(let player of value){
        let p: Player = new Player(player.name, player.id, player.ready);
        players.push(p);
      }
      for(let i=players.length; i<8; i++){
        players.push(Player.emptyPlayer());
      }
      setTimeout(()=>{this.players = players, 100; console.log(this.players);}); //THIS console.log displays the correct data
    });
    this.client.socket.emit('query-gamename', (value)=>this.gamename=value);
    this.client.socket.emit('query-utilname', (value)=>this.utilGamename=value);
    if(this.hosting){
      this.client.socket.emit('query-min-players', num=>this.minPlayers = num);
    }
  }
```

html for the template:

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th><th>Ready</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let player of players">
      <td>{{ player.name }}</td><td>{{ player.formatReady() }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button (click)="quit()">{{ hosting ? 'Disband' : 'Quit' }}</button>
  <button (click)="handleReadyButton()"
  [disabled]="!startReadyEnabled">{{ hosting ? 'Start' : ready ? 'Unready' : 'Ready' }}</button>
</div>
```

All the data comes in and is assigned correctly, but not displayed, and when I try to interact the players array becomes an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what happened to me is an actual bug in the angular routing system, but I did figure out a way to work around it. Instead of querying my server for information when the router fired the navigation end event, I bind the query function to mouseenter in the top-level element of the component. This ensures that data is not delivered until the router is completely done modifying/building the model however it does that.